# how "shell export" behave in makefile

Tags: makefile, export, environment

there are three files:

test1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib1
```

test2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Makefile:

```
.PHONY : all
all:
    ./test1.sh && ./test2.sh
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib1 && ./test2.sh
```

make result:

```
./test1.sh && ./test2.sh
/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib1 && ./test2.sh
/usr/local/lib1
```

makefile always create a child process to execute command. what is the difference between first line command and second line of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with make; you'd see the same behavior if you ran those commands directly from the shell command line.

When you run a command like `./test1.sh` (no matter how it's done) that invokes a new shell.  The new shell has a new copy of the environment of the parent process.  When you modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inside `./test1.sh` you modify that copy.  Then the shell exits, and that modified copy of the environment is destroyed.  Remember it's *impossible* in a POSIX/UNIX environment to *ever* modify the environment of your parent process (directly).

In the second example you first set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the environment of the parent, then you invoke `./test2.sh` which makes a copy of the parent's environment, so it inherits the new setting.

If you want to have a script that modifies the environment of the current shell you *must* use the source operation to run it; this causes the current shell to run the script rather than creating a new shell to run the script:

```
. ./test1.sh && ./test2.sh
```

The `.` shell command is the standard way to source a script instead of running it.